# Sql view from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, view

I am stuck in a query, please help.
I want to create view.

### Table1

```
ID | Acode | Bcode | Ccode |
1  | 10    | 101   | 102   |
2  | 11    | 100   | 101   |
3  | 10    | 100   | 102   |
```

### Table2

```
Acode | Adescription |
10    | English      |
11    | Math         |
```

### Table3

```
Bcode | Bdescription |
100   | Grade A      |
101   | Grade B      |
```

### Table4

```
Ccode | Cdescription |
 100  | Level A      |
 101  | Level B      |
 102  | Level C      |
```

I want to print all rows in Table1 with description from other tables based on code in table1.

Output should be:
data

### NewView

```
ID | Acode |Adescription | Bcode | Bdescription | Ccode | Cdescription |
1  | 10    | English     | 101   |   Grade B    |  102  |   Level C    |
2  | 11    | Math        | 100   |   Grade A    |  101  |   Level B    |
```

### 3  | 10    | English     | 100   |   Grade A    |  102  |   Level C    |

I created left join but it returns more rows than actual in table1. I want to have only all records from table1 with description from other tables.

Please help

Comment: Please edit your question and show your query along with sample data.

Comment: Perhaps there is more than one row for the same value in one or more of the joined tables.  You will get more rows than in Table1 in that case.

Comment: Yes that is happening. I only want to get records from table1. and want to show descriptions from another tables based on code in table1. How can I create view for this which give me only all records of table1 with descriptions. Join or nested query, not sure hoe to get it.

Comment: When there is more than one row for the same code but different descriptions, which description should be returned?  Show sample data and expected results like Gordon suggested to clarify your question.

Comment: I have edited the sample data. Codes in each table (Table2, Table3, Table4) are unique so codes can not be duplicate in Table2, Table3, Table4. These tables are only used to display descriptions.

Comment: @AmarpalSandhu . . . Your sample data would not generate multiple rows.

Comment: I dont want to generate multiple row. I just need all records from table1 with all descriptions. I think, nested query may work but dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example.  Since you didn't post your original query attempt, we can't really say why you were getting multiple rows.  No need for a `LEFT JOIN` unless you are missing codes in the joined tables.

```
SELECT  Table1.ID
      , Table1.Acode
      , Table2.Adescription
      , Table1.Bcode
      , Table3.Bdescription
      , Table1.Ccode
      , Table4.Cdescription
FROM    dbo.Table1
        JOIN dbo.Table2 ON Table2.Acode = Table1.Acode
        JOIN dbo.Table3 ON Table3.Bcode = Table1.Bcode
        JOIN dbo.Table4 ON Table4.Ccode = Table1.Ccode;
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Sorry I could not add full query here as it was just example and actual query has 18 tables and would be long and lengthy and confusing here.   It works well but if description is not entered or left blank then it skips the whole record.

Comment: @AmarpalSandhu, if you are missing rows (not evident in the sample data), then change the inner joins to left joins,  You will get duplicates only of the code values are duplicated in the joined tables.

Comment: Thank you I tried this both ways, either it misses the records where descriptions are empty or gives duplicate records where same description  is assigned to another record in table1.  I want to have purely records from table1  and get the description where it matches the code.

Comment: If I add LEFT JOIN, I am not missing any records, but only duplicate records on table3 where same code is used in table1 record for another user.

Comment: @AmarpalSandhu, I don't see any duplicates in your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help

LEFT Join worked well. I tried to narrow down the tables one by one and found the table where I was getting duplicate records. After finding table I found that I forgot to add Unique key and 1 record (Description) was entered twice which was giving duplicate records and total number of rows were increased.

Thanks all to help me out,and Dan Guzman to point me for duplicate codes.